# Biggest consecutive value for consecutive observations above threshold per ID

Tags: r

I looked some of the answers on similar topic, but unfortunately none worked.
I have a .df of time series and I would like to calculate and keep as  separate column only the biggest value of consecutive observations per ID.

[image]

...after mutating the new column into the existing .df, will sumarise the new column with `c(max)`, but for the time being, it should stay as such in the existing .df, regardless of the fact how it looks.

Is `rle()` a solution here or do I need to create a function (x) to be applied with `rollsum()/rollmax()`?

Thank You.

Mr. K

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b"), year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), obs = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `rle`. One way in base R would be,

```
with(df, ave(obs, ID, FUN = function(i){i1 <- rle(i); max(i1$lengths[i1$values == 1])}))
# [1] 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: ...it seems that it counts a mean value for all observations, instead of per observations per tree_id.

Comment: It does exactly what you described. It counts the consecutive 1s and presents the max

Comment: Apologiese, my mistake was in the applying of the code. Awesome help, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`, we can use `rleid` to get id for consecutive occurrence, use `table` to get the count and select `max` from each group.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, max_conc := max(table(rleid(obs))), by = ID]

df
#    ID year obs max_conc
# 1:  a 2012   1        2
# 2:  a 2013   1        2
# 3:  a 2014   0        2
# 4:  a 2015   1        2
# 5:  a 2016   0        2
# 6:  b 2010   1        4
# 7:  b 2011   0        4
# 8:  b 2012   1        4
# 9:  b 2013   1        4
#10:  b 2014   1        4
#11:  b 2015   1        4
```

Comment: It counts a  total of all observations, instead of the biggest consecutive sum of obs = 1 :(

Comment: @Mr.K It calculates `biggest value of consecutive observations per ID.`. Are you looking for something else?